# Scoring - $21\%$ chance - probability

Tags: probability

If we have four shooters with each of them having a $21\%$ chance of scoring and four rounds independent of one another, what is the probability of all four of them scoring all four shots? Would it be $\frac{21}{100}+\frac{21}{100}+\frac{21}{100}+\frac{21}{100}$? Thank you.

**EDIT:** Each shooter would have only one round, i.e. one shooter shooting during the 1st round with a $21\%$ chance of scoring, another shooter shooting during the 2nd round with the same chance of scoring, a 3rd shooter shooting during the 3rd round with the same change and the last shooter shooting during the last round. So what would the probability of all of them scoring during their respective rounds be? I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: So if you had six shooters, they have a 126% chance to score? Try a multiplication instead if you want the probability of coinciding events

Comment: I suggest you use Mathjax to make your question clearer. You can find more information in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of this as the chance that one person shoots $4$ shots correctly in a row. By your method, the answer would be $\frac{21\cdot5}{100}$ for $5$ shooters which would clearly be over $1$ . It also wouldn’t make sense to say that getting a streak of $5$ is higher than that of getting $1$, since getting a streak of $5$ would require getting a streak of $1$. The correct way is not to add them, but to multiply them. The correct answer should be $\left(\frac{21}{100}\right)^4$ which is about $0.00194$